# getting all arguments and keyword arguments in elixir

Tags: elixir

Does elixir has any way to obtain all arguments and keyword arguments from a function and send them to another function?

Something like:

```
def func1("test", 10) do
  ...
end

def func2("test", "string", "another string", 10) do
  ...
end

def check(type, *args, **kwargs) do
  case type do
    :func1 -> func1(*args, **kwargs)
    :func2 -> func2(*args, **kwargs)
  end
end

check(:func1, "test", 10)
check(:func2, "test", "string", "another string", 10)
```

Note func1 and func2 might now have same num of params

In python you could achieve this using **kwargs and *args, I am not sure if elixir has something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elixir doesn't support functions with variable number of arguments. The best you can do is to accept a list of arguments in `check` and use `apply` to dynamically pass it to a function:

```
def check(type, args) do
  case type do
    :func1 -> apply(__MODULE__, :func1, args)
    :func2 -> apply(__MODULE__, :func2, args)
  end
end
```

You can now call `check` like this:

```
check(:func1, [:foo, :bar, baz: :quux])
```

and it'll internally call:

```
func1(:foo, :bar, baz: :quux)
```